# Counting number of items based on condition

Tags: python, list, numpy, counting

I have the following dataset.

1. 1 2
2. 2 5
3. 3 4
4. 4 7
5. 6 8
6. 7 6

My aim is to have a count of numbers in column 2 which are less than or equal 6. The numbers in column 2 which are less than or equal to 6 are 2,4,5 and 6. So, i want the output to be 4 as 2,4,5 and 6 are all appearing once, so total appearance count=4.

My approach has been:

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A.txt')
x=data[:,1]
Count=list(x.flatten()).count(6)  #it only counts the number of times 6 appears in the list.
```

Any suggestion on how to manipulate the code to get a count for numbers equal or less than 6 would mean a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
count = len([i for i in x if i <= 6])
```

Comment: If counting is all that is required try `sum(1 for _ in x if _ <= 6)`.